# How to use a variable as part of a JavaScript path

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code:

```
applyBefore: {
            backgroundImage: 'url(/myPath/furniture/images/careers/birds/pigeon_flap_medium.gif?' + Math.random() + ')',
            contentFlyOut: {
                direction: 'top',
                delay: 0.5,
                node: '#our-history-content'
            }
        }
```

... which works fine, BUT, I need the value of '/myPath' to be whatever the value of a variable called 'binaryContextRoot' is, as this code will run of different servers where the value of 'binaryContextRootwill differ server to server.

I'm struggling with the correct syntax to get 'binaryContextRoot' in the 'url' path.

I have tried:

```
backgroundImage: 'url("+binaryContextRoot+"/furniture/images...
```

where 'binaryContextRoute' is '/myPath', but with no success. The path is not recognised/found, so obvioulsy the value of "+binaryContextRoot+" is incorrect.

Can anyone help please? :)

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
backgroundImage: 'url(' + binaryContextRoot + '/furniture/images...'
```

Comment: That is superb RASG! So obviuous when I look at it. Many thanks! :)